# 3D printed titanium durability/material quality concerns

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering

What is the material strength of titanium 3D printed parts....compared to cast or machined parts?
also how do they bond the individual pieces?

Comment: Look at the material datasheets for the 3D printable titanium alloy. Machined will be stronger. Unsure about cast. What do you mean bond? Like sticking two separately  printed pieces together?

Comment: In the printing process...how do the individual pieces hold together

Comment: The strength can vary widely, depending upon the skill of the operator and the quality of the equipment/powder.  Bonding can be done with epoxies or even welding (usually spray welding).

Comment: @LazyReader 3D printing metal has two methods I know of called DMLS and SLM. The first is sintering and the second is melting.